# diff-mode: refine all hunks when opening a diff file?

Tags: diff-mode

`diff-mode` provides `diff-refine-hunk` function to refine the highlighting of the current hunk. However, by default, only `diff-hunk-next` or explicit `diff-refine-hunk` calls will do this job -- hunks will not be refined by default. I wrote the following snippet to refine all hunks when I enter `diff-mode`:

```
(defun my-diff-hunks-highlight-all ()
  "Highlight all hunks in diff-mode."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((last-point))
      (while (not (equal (point) last-point))
        (setq last-point (point))
        (diff-refine-hunk)
        (diff-hunk-next)))))
(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook 'my-diff-hunks-highlight-all)
```

However, it turns out that only the last hunk will be refined. Is there any reason that this approach fails? What should be the proper way to do it?

**Related Emacs bug**: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18128

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is the following form in the definition of `diff-mode-hook`. It removes all the refinement overlays that you created with your function `my-diff-hunks-highlight-all` immediately after starting up `diff-mode` and initializing `font-lock-mode`.

```el
(declare-function 'diff-hunk-next "diff-mode")

(defun my-diff-refine-all ()
  "Refine all diffs."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (condition-case nil
        (diff-beginning-of-hunk t)
      (error (diff-hunk-next)))
    (condition-case nil
        (while (not (eobp))
          (diff-refine-hunk)
          (diff-hunk-next))
      (user-error) ;; catches "No next hunk." from `diff-hunk-next' if there is garbage at the end of the file.
      )))

(defun my-diff-hunks-highlight-all ()
  "Highlight all hunks in diff-mode."
  (add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook #'my-diff-refine-all t t))

(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook 'my-diff-hunks-highlight-all)
```

Comment: The call of `(diff-beginning-of-hunk t)` does not seem necessary (as diff-refine-hunk calls it), and it causes problems when reading git format patches: diff-beginning-of-file-and-junk: Can’t find the beginning of the file

Comment: Seems the other parts also cause error for git format patches... But running `diff-hunk-next` after loading a git format patch works as expected. Don't know why.

Comment: @xuhdev This is a problem of `diff --git ...`. This form of `diff` appends and prepends stuff and includes binary diffs encoded as ascii. I tried to make the lisp code more roboust for these cases.

Comment: This actually still cause some issues with [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl). It works well after replacing all the `condition-case` with `ignore-errors`.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me when I test on two small files (i.e., there are not many diffs).

```lisp
(defun my-diff-hunks-highlight-all ()
  "Highlight all hunks in diff-mode."
  (interactive)
  (run-at-time 0.1 nil
               (lambda ()
                 (save-excursion
                   (goto-char (point-min))
                   (while (not (eobp))
                     (diff-hunk-next 1)
                     (sit-for 0.01))))))

(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook 'my-diff-hunks-highlight-all)
```

- I didn't call `diff-refine-hunk` explicitly since it will be called from `diff-hunk-next` if `diff-auto-refine-mode` is on (it is by default).
- `(run-at-time 0.1 ...)`: gives 0.1 seconds to diff-mode to be ready
- `(sit-for 0.01)`: gives 0.01 seconds to `diff-refine-hunk` to make effect

The above is not a very good solution, I think. You might need to adjust the times. There should be other element way. I don't know diff-mode very much.