# Change colours for character differences for diff-mode

Tags: faces, customize, diff-mode

I've changed my `diff-mode` colours according to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079830/how-to-configure-highlighting-in-emacs-diff-mode), but the character-based differences are shown in the original(?) and very bright colours, making them quite unreadable.

How do I change the colours that show the char-by-char differences on the removed/added lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With diff-refine faces:

```el
(defun update-diff-refine-colors ()
  "update the colors for diff faces"
  (set-face-attribute 'diff-refine-added nil
                      :foreground "white" :background "darkgreen")
  (set-face-attribute 'diff-refine-removed nil
                      :foreground "white" :background "darkred")
  (set-face-attribute 'diff-refine-changed nil
                      :foreground "white" :background "darkblue"))
(eval-after-load "diff-mode"
  '(update-diff-refine-colors))
```

Comment: Very good! I merged them into one function. However strangely, earlier all of my diff chunks were automatically refined (char differences showed automatically). Now I have to do it manually. How do I enable it automatically? The linked article suggests a snippet to enable this, but it really did happen on my machine without any such snippet... https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28271/diff-mode-refine-all-hunks-when-opening-a-diff-file

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Emacs does'nt refine by default. You need to used a function for that.

Answer (score 2):

There are more faces involved than the ones mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4079830/729907) you pointed to.  The answer is to use `C-u C-x =` to find out what faces are involved.  Those are the ones you need to customize.

Use `M-x customize-face` to customize the faces you are interested in. If you don't know which faces they are, put the cursor on that highlighted text and use `C-u C-x =`.  Look near the bottom of `*Help*` for the face name.

From @djangoliv's answer it seems that these are the faces you need to customize: `diff-refine-added`, `diff-refine-removed`, `diff-refine-changed`.

So just `M-x customize-face diff-refine-added` and define the face as you like.

Do the same for `diff-refine-removed` and `diff-refine-changed`.

Easy, persistent, and the way Emacs wants to help you customize faces. See the Emacs manual, node [Specific Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specific-Customization.html).

Comment: Ah! That's a brilliant way to find out in the future!